Next.js application connects to MongoDB Atlas and deploys to Azure App Service. Its builds successfully and is deployed, but it fails to start
Deployment Process:
Application is developed using Next.js.
MongoDB Atlas is used for the database.
The application is built and deployed using GitHub Actions.
The application settings in Azure have MONGODB_URI and DATABASE_NAME set correctly.
When I check the logs in Azure Portal, I see the following errors:
Container app-nurse-with-mongodb-atlas_0_f6815f95 for site app-nurse-with-mongodb-atlas has exited, failing site start
Container app-nurse-with-mongodb-atlas_0_7250d342 for site app-nurse-with-mongodb-atlas has exited, failing site start
What I've Tried:
Verified that MONGODB_URI and DATABASE_NAME are correctly set in Azure Application settings.
Confirmed that the MongoDB Atlas cluster has IP whitelisting configured to allow connections from Azure IP ranges.
Local Testing:The application runs and connects to MongoDB Atlas successfully on my local machine.
Environment Variables
Made sure all necessary environment variables from .env.local are added to Azure Application settings.
Public Access:
Ensured that the MongoDB Atlas is accessible from the internet and added necessary IP addresses.
Environment Details:
Next.js Version: 14.2
Azure App Service Plan: BAsic
Deployment Method: GitHub Actions
Database: MongoDB Atlas
#azure
Question:
Why does my Next.js application fail to start on Azure even though it connects to MongoDB Atlas successfully locally? How can I resolve the "Failed to retrieve collection list due to Firewall configuration" and container exit issues?
additionaly in preview version of app when I try to create in azure web app with database, I was errow with "Failed to retrieve collection list due to Firewall configuration." but I had public access
In general, I want to next js application with mongo db, which works correctly locally and on vercel release to production, on its own server

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Milencja If Possible, share your GitHub Repo?
